# Animate background-image height

Tags: jquery, css

Since i'm new to jQuery but would still like to achieve an effect where a background image animates from 100% to 50% when 250px from the top, I tried to put some codes together I found online, this is what it looks like:

```
#page {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

function getBackgroundImageUrl(#page) {
  if (!($element instanceof jQuery)) {
    $element = $($element);
  }

  var imageUrl = $('#page').css('background-image');
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(scroll>250){
    $('imageUrl').stop(true,false);
   $('imageUrl').animate({'height':427,5},200);
  } else {
    $('imageUrl').stop(true,false);
    $('imageUrl').animate({'height':855},200);
  }
}
```

(Wasn't sure how to change `427,5` into 50% or `855` into 100%), however I don't see the image at all after trying to test out the code, how can I get this effect?

Comment: Your code is not working. Please fix this `scoll`, `$element` is not define. You need to understand what you copy first.

Comment: I changed the typo